# what is the difference between 'AND' operator and 'OR' operator in c

Tags: c, if-statement, negation, logical-or, logical-and

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int count;
    char ch;
    for(a=1;a<=100;a++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a);
        printf("do you want to break loop(y/n):");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        
        if(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

this only works when I enter
`if(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')` or    `if(ch!='y' && ch!='Y')`
and does not work when I enter
`if(ch=='y' && ch=='Y')`
while both are true in all the condition

Comment: It is impossible, that `ch` is `y` and (`&&`) `Y` at the same time.

Comment: If they were both true, that would imply that `'y' == 'Y'`, which isn't true.

Comment: @pzaenger thank you for your answer but can you elaborate please why It is impossible, that ch is y and (&&) Y at the same time will be very helpful for the newbie like me.

Comment: Because `'y'` is not the same thing as `'Y'`.  `ch` holds only one value, so it could be one or the other of those, but not both at the same time.  *And you know this*, otherwise you would not be testing both alternatives in the first place.

Comment: These are working pretty much as `AND` and `OR` in English. Simply read the expression aloud. "If ch equals to lowercase Y OR it equals to uppercase Y, then....". And compare to: "If ch equals to lowercase Y AND it equals to uppercase Y, then....". Now read the second one again. Can it happen that it equals to *both* uppercase and lowercase in the same time?

Comment: @John, it does accept all the values like operators, int, char until the loop terminates.

Comment: Sorry to have been unclear. `ch` holds only one value *at a time*.

Answer (score 2):

`'y'` is not equal to `'Y'`, so `ch` cannot be equal to both *at the same time*.  If `ch == 'y'` is true, then `ch == 'Y'` *must* be false and vice versa.  Thus the expression `ch == 'y' && ch == 'Y'` can *never* be true, because `ch` cannot be two different values at the same time.  It can only be one ***or*** (hint hint hint) the other at any given moment.

Answer (score 1):

How can one letter be at the same time equal to 'y' or 'Y'?

The user can enter only one letter either 'y' or 'Y' or some other letter.

So this if statement

```
if(ch=='y' && ch=='Y')
```

does not make a sense. The condition of the if statement always evaluates to logical false.

This if statement

```
if(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
```

determines whether the user entered either the letter 'y' or the letter 'Y'.

This if statement

```
if(ch!='y' && ch!='Y')
```

means that the user entered some other letter that is not 'y' and not 'Y'. The above statement also can be rewritten like

```
if( !( ch == 'y' || ch =='Y' ) )
```

This if statement

```
if(ch!='y' && ch!='Y')
```

is opposite to this if statement

```
if(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
```

That is when the condition in the first if statemen evaluates to true then the condition in the second if statement evaluates to false and vice versa.

The negation of this expression

```
!( ch=='y' || ch=='Y' )
```

is equivalent to this expression

```
( ch != 'y' && ch != 'Y' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Read and study the references below, after that you will have a better understanding what the differences are and what your statements means.

**Logical operators**

- [Logical AND](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical#Logical_AND)
- [Logical OR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical#Logical_OR)

**Comparison operators**

- [Equality operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_comparison#Equality_operators)